# Explaining window function frames

Tags: sql

Imagine, table with 2 columns - order no, value.

```
;with SourceTable as (
    select *
        from (values
            (1, null)
            ,(2, 5)
            ,(3, null)
            ,(4, null)
            ,(5, 2)
            ,(6, 1)
        ) as T(OrderNo, Value)
)
select
       *
       ,first_value(Value) over (
           order by
               case when Value is not null then 0 else 1 end
               , OrderNo
           rows between current row and unbounded following
       ) as X
   from SourceTable
order by OrderNo
```

The issue is that it returns exactly same resultset as SourceTable. I don't understand why. E.g., if first row is processed (OrderNo = 1) I'd expect column X returns 5 because frame should include all rows (current row and unbound following) and it orders by Value - nonnulls first, then by OrderNo. So first row in frame should be OrderNo=2. Obviously it doesn't work like that but I don't get why.

Much appreciated if someone explains how is constructed the first frame.

Many thanks

Comment: How is this question different from:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58418463/unexpected-behavior-of-window-function-first-value/58420288#58420288?

Comment: Are you trying to implement IGNORE NULLS clause: **[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=be80d3136d4bfaedefe418cdab3bdc2d)**?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - The other one was formulated more about solution. Either way, answers are solutions but they don't explain really why it doesn't work as I expect

Comment: @LukaszSzozda - this time, I try to understand what rows are selected when column X is calculated. It looks like ignore null but I really want to understand better how it's defined. I read a lot about it but I couldn't find any explanation of more complicated query like I show. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I modified your query to investigte - I explicitly added the CASE as a column result, and then sorted the entire result set as your Window is ordered by:

```
;with SourceTable as (
    select *
        from (values
            (1, null)
            ,(2, 5)
            ,(3, null)
            ,(4, null)
            ,(5, 2)
            ,(6, 1)
        ) as T(OrderNo, Value)
)
select
       *
       ,case when Value is not null then 0 else 1 end AS CaseSort
    ,Value
       ,first_value(Value) over (
           order by
               case when Value is not null then 0 else 1 end
               , OrderNo
           rows between current row and unbounded following
       ) as X
   from SourceTable
order by 3,OrderNo
```

Where you can see that "first_value" for the window matches the "Value" amount in each of the result rows.